# Probability of at least two balls of same color

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification

> Let's assume we have $4$ sets of $8$ coloured balls: red, blue, black and white. If we draw $n$-times without replacing, where $2\leq n \leq 32$, what is the probability of getting at least 2 red balls?

My attempt is setting this up as a Laplace experiment. I will put different numbers on each ball, i.e. red balls get the numbers from $1$ to $8$, blue balls from $9$ to $16$ ... So the sample space $\Omega$ consists of $n$-tupels whose entries are pairwise different numbers. Each element $\omega \in \Omega$ has the same probabilty to get drawn, $p(\omega)=\frac{(32-n)!}{32!}$. Now I count all the possible elements in $\Omega$ which contain at least $2$ numbers in the range from $1$ to $8$: 
$${n \choose 2}\frac{8!}{(8-2)!}\frac{30!}{(30-n+2)!}$$
Then I receive the desired probability by:
$$\frac{{n \choose 2}\frac{8!}{(8-2)!} \frac{30!}{(30-n+2)!}}{\frac{(32-n)!}{32!}}$$

Is this correct?

---

**Edit**

This is my new approach:

To avoid double counting I separatly count all possible elements in $\Omega$ which contain exactly $2$, $3$, ...$n$ red balls:

$$\sum_{i=2}^8 {n \choose i}\frac{8!}{(8-i)!}\frac{24!}{(24-n+i)!}. $$

Where ${n \choose i}$ denotes the possibilites to select $i$-many spots among the $n$ draws and $\frac{8!}{(8-i)!}$ represents all ways to draw $i$-many red balls out of $8$ red balls in an ordered manner. Finally, $\frac{24!}{(24-n+i)!}$ counts all ways to fill up the remaining $(n-i)$ slots of the $n$-draws with balls that are not red. To receive the desired probability I divide by $\frac{32!}{(32-n)!}$ which yields:
$$\frac{\sum_{i=2}^8 {n \choose i}\frac{8!}{(8-i)!}\frac{24!}{(24-n+i)!}}{\frac{32!}{(32-n)!}}. $$

Any comments are appreciated!

Comment: There might be a lot of double counting. E.g. the set $\{1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 11, 12 \}$ get counted 3 times.

Comment: @CalvinLin, I always fall into the trap of double counting .... :(

Comment: It should be $32!$ instead of $30!$ in the denominator of your last expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start with counting all possible (unordered) combinations with 0 and 1 red balls:

$$N_0=\binom{24}n;\quad N_1=\binom81\binom{24}{n-1}$$
and compute the probability as
$$
1-\frac {N_0+N_1}N,
$$
where
$$
N=\binom{32}n
$$
is the overall number of combinations.

Comment: $N_0=\binom{24}{n}; N_1=\binom{8}{1}\binom{24}{n-1}$ and $N=\binom{32}{n}$

Comment: I agree that this form of the result representation looks much nicer. Thanks!

Comment: @user I have edited the OP and added a new approach which, I think, is equivalent to yours.

Comment: @Philipp As soon as you correct the mistake in your approach it will be equivalent to mine although unnecessarily complicated (e.g. you add 6 terms instead of 2).

Comment: @user, yes my approach seems complicated but I wanted to cover the cases when $n>24$. I am not sure if your approach is also valid for $n>24$? The answer from Ymh seems to adress this issue correctly. What do you think?

Comment: @Philipp This solution is valid for all $n$, as $\binom{24}{n}=0$ for $n>24$ and $\binom{24}{n-1}=0$ for $n>25$

Comment: @DanielMathias, ah okay I didn't know that the binomial coefficient then attains $0$, thanks :)

Comment: @Philipp It is usual and **very** useful property of the binomial coefficients that they automatically take care about such issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't follow Your logic, perhaps You could explain it better. Your probability equation gives $p>1$ and fails at $n=1$.

I think it's a lottery. We have $\binom{32}{n}$ possible draws, for $n\leq24$ there are $\binom{8}{0}\binom{24}{n}$ combinations with 0 red balls and for $n\leq25$ there are $\binom{8}{1}\times\binom{24}{n-1}$ combinations with 1 red ball.

$$p(r\geq2) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $n=1$} \\
1-\frac{\binom{24}{n}}{\binom{32}{n}}-\frac{8\times\binom{24}{n-1}}{\binom{32}{n}} & \text{if $2\leq n\leq 24$} \\
1-\frac{8\times\binom{24}{24}}{\binom{32}{n}} & \text{if $n=25$} \\
1 & \text{if $n>25$}
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Yes you are right concerning my probability. In my first attempt the probability was wrong due to double counting. I have edited the OP. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Now it's correct and I get it. I think You should sum up to 8 to avoid trying to find elements containing 9+ red balls and having factorials of negative value show up in terms, but then it's better to go with min(n,8) instead to avoid i>n binomial coefficients. I read that they are 0 for positive integers, software may just throw an error.

Comment: Thanks for the remark I have edited my answer and replaced the $n$ by an $8$.